# Facebook account asks for verification, but does not send out the verification

Tags: facebook

When I try to recover my account using email, it says:

> "Enter code
> We sent an 8-digit code to the email you chose. Please enter the code here once it arrives."
> "An error occurred while sending the message"

When I try the other option of "Approve your login on another computer"
It says:

> "Approve Login
> To continue, please approve this login on a phone or computer you've used before."

Shows me my computer OS and browser I'm currently using, I press continue and it says: "Login was not approved"

I couldn't find any helpful solution. What is going on?